# How to add a static row in expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How to add this single row as static in every expandablelistview ?

[image]

this is my layout inflater :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
    android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <TextView
            android:text="#"
            android:id="@+id/txt_rank_standings"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:text="TEAM"
            android:id="@+id/txtteam"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_rank_standings"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_rank_standings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_points_standings"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txt_points_standings"
            android:text="P" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_points_standings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="PTS" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_rank_standings_final"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_rank_standings"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_name_standings_final"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="العهد"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtteam"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_rank_standings_final"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_rank_standings_final"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_played_standings_final"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_points_standings_final"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txt_points_standings_final"
      />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_points_standings_final"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:text="12"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_points_standings"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

i added this single row to the layout inflater but the problem is i am getting something like this:

[image]

The single row is being repeated 3 times in the expandablelistview.

So, How do i make this row static inside the expandablelistview?

UPDATED:

This is my fragment activity which contains the expandablelistview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                <ExpandableListView
                    android:id="@+id/elv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                </ExpandableListView>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the custom row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative_standings"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:text="#"
        android:id="@+id/txt_rank_standings"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="TEAM"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_rank_standings"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_rank_standings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_points_standings"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txt_points_standings"
        android:text="P" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_points_standings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="PTS" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATED:

When i added the header layout it works but the first child row is removed as this pic shows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article that has step by step instructions on how to accomplish just that - https://robusttechhouse.com/how-to-add-header-footer-to-expandablelistview-childview/

In order to create an expandable list view with a header in the child view, you will need four XML layout files.

1. The main layout containing the `ExpandableListView`
2. The group item layout
3. The child item layout
4. The header of the child view.

The trick is to get the first row and set it as a header:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ParentObject currentParent = getGroup(groupPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //The first row is used as header
    if(childPosition == 0){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_header, null);
        TextView txtHeader = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
        txtHeader.setText(currentParent.textToHeader);
    }

    //Fix the prior out of bound exception
    if(childPosition > 0 &&* childPosition < getChildrenCount(groupPosition) - 1){
      ChildObject currentChild = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition - 1);
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);

      //Set your fields for the header here... i.e
      TextView txtChildName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtChildName);
      TextView txtChildAge = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtChildAge);
    }

  return view;
}
```

Then increase the Custom Adapter's `getChildrenCount()` return by `1`, to accommodate for the one we are using for the header. Like this:

```
@override
public int getChildrenCount(int i){
  return yourModel.get(i).childObjects.size() + 1;
}
```

**Layout holding it altogether**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <ExpandableListView
       android:id="@+id/elv"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"></ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout for the Parent Rows**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/parent_background"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMother"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFather"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Layout for the Child Row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/child_background"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_left"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtChildName"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtChildAge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Layout for the Header**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/hf_background"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_left">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Header"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thx Dayan i will try it now

Comment: Super fast,correct and reliable answer !
Thanks a lot Dear @Dayan

Comment: i have one more question please..i will update the question

Comment: @MahdiHraybi Updated answer, just add `1` to the `getChildrenCount()` in the custom `BaseExpandableAdapter`. Also note that it's not a good idea to modify your question like you did, it's confusing for others. I recommend adding that part of the question as a comment here since I already answered the first part.

Comment: Sorry i will do that next time .

I am getting :                                                                                java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3

Can i edit the question and post my adapter class

Comment: @MahdiHraybi Forgot to add a part that was included in that article, it will fix the out of bound exception. Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147530/discussion-between-mahdi-hraybi-and-dayan).

Comment: I have reviewed my code and added this line and worked perfectly :

  if(childPosition>0 && childPosition<getChildrenCount(groupPosition)) {
            final Standings_data teamData = (Standings_data) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition - 1);

//do stuff
}